# WordPress Large file image not showing dimensions

Tags: wordpress

[image]

[image]

Issue is dimensions missing in one screenshot. If I upload 6mb file size it does not work. But if I upload a small size image i.e 1 mb then dimension are showing. Any help?

I am using latest wordpresss version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Its working for me.

```
  function upload_size_limit_filter_set( $size ) {
         return 1536000*14;//Size in Kb
   }
   add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'upload_size_limit_filter_set',12 );
```

Comment: not working for me.I passed your provided code on functions.php.FYI,I already setup uploading image size is 
Maximum upload file size: 40 MB.

Comment: Are you working localhost or server? you need to max upload size in php.init

Comment: Yes,I have updated in php.ini max upload size =40MB.When I migrate website on local server.It is working fine there.But not on live server

Comment: you need to set in server also